# C# web application without IIS

Tags: c#, iis, owin, katana, mod-mono

For web application development using C#, IIS seems to be the standard choice of web server. But are there any other options? I want to use Linux for my web server.

As far as I can see the other options are:

1. Make your web server program handle the IIS stuff yourself. (As long as you don't need a lot of IIS features, this won't be too expensive)
2. Use [XSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSP_(software))
3. Use Apache Tomcat with [mod_mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/)
4. Use another web server like [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) or [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) (Is this even possible with C#?)
5. Use that [OWIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Web_Interface_for_.NET) stuff (Are there implementations of this which are mature enough to consider yet?)
6. Something else I haven't considered ... ?

Which of these options is the most viable for a web application in the long term?

I'm mostly concerned about the long term maintainability of the project, rather than the server being able to handle high volume loads.

Comment: Feedback on how to fix this question would be helpful

Comment: use IIS! Simple really. why reinvent the wheel. if you want cross platform, then take a look at .NET 4.6/ASP.NET 5.0 and DNX

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Is IIS cross platform?

Comment: no it is not. Windows only. But as I said, if you want cross platform, check out .NET 4.6/ASP.NET 5 and DNX

Comment: @sav, this question is too broad, since there is no context. If you asked what should be used in your particular situation, then there could be some objective advice. Otherwise, you'll just hear vague opinion-based answers.

Comment: In linux, I know there's an asp.net hosting service "Jexus", but beware of the compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1

1. Install Mono+XSP
2. Launch ASP.NET web-app using XSP on different port e.g. 8001
3. Proxy this port through nginx to 80

#### Option 2 (Better)

1. Wait for ASP.NET 5 ([MVC6](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc)) release with complete Linux support
2. Use standalone-application approach (OWIN-Like) on different port e.g. 8001
3. Proxy this port through nginx to 80

On both ways you will need to install Mono, and I recommend installing latest one, not the one that, for example, Ubuntu PPA gives.

Also, since you are concerned about long-term you should really wait for Option 2 since it's going to be released in next couple of months.

If you *really* cannot wait those months and do not want to work on beta-product and then migrate to stable only option I see is [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/) which is web-app framework written in C# that has full Linux support now.